# Transformation of disaster data time series for recurrent neural networks

Tags: time-series, data-transformation

**Background:**

I'm doing an asset pricing project based on this paper https://papers.ssrn.com/sol3/papers.cfm?abstract_id=3350138, where I feed time series of macroeconomic data along with cross-sectional medians of firm-specific data into a RNN to obtain estimates of hidden states that indicate the "condition" of the economy. The frequency of the data is monthly. Regarding the transformations they state:

> We apply standard transformations to the time series data. We use the
>    transformations suggested in McCracken and Ng (2016), and
>    define transformations for the 46 median and the 8 time series from
>    Welch and Goyal (2007) to obtain stationary time series. The
>    transformations include: (1) no transformation; (2)$\Delta x_{t}$
>   (3)$\Delta^{2} x_{t}$ (4) $\log\left(x_{t}\right)$ (5) $\Delta \log
>  \left(x_{t}\right)$;(6) $\Delta^{2} \log \left(x_{t}\right)$; and (7)
>    $\Delta\left(x_{t} / x_{t-1}-1.0\right) .$ A detailed description of
>    the macroeconomic variables as well as their corre- sponding
>   transformations (tCode) are collected in Appendix G.A.

Given the current influence of COVID-19, I thought it would be interesting to use some kind of disaster data as additional, and maybe valuable information. As we all can observe, such events have an influence on present and future consumption as well as general economic activity and hence on asset prices.

**Data:**

I downloaded a dataset from https://public.emdat.be/ for the period from 1960 up to date. It contains data on many types of disasters in different places all over the world including when the specific events started and when they ended. For example, there are more general categories such as disaster groups:

**['Natural', 'Technological', 'Complex Disasters']**

and more detailed subgroups

**['Geophysical',
 'Meteorological',
 'Technological',
 'Hydrological',
 'Biological',
 'Climatological',
 'Complex Disasters',
 'Extra-terrestrial']** (only one 'Extra-terrestrial' data point; meteor in Russia, 2013)

Or even more detailed disaster types:

**['Earthquake',
 'Storm',
 'Transport accident',
 'Miscellaneous accident',
 'Flood',
 'Landslide',
 'Extreme temperature',
 'Volcanic activity',
 'Epidemic',
 'Industrial accident',
 'Drought',
 'Wildfire',
 'Mass movement (dry)',
 'Insect infestation',
 'Complex Disasters',
 'Impact',
 'Animal accident']**

And geographically they are categorized into 'Continents', 'Regions' and of course 'Countries'. Now, working generally with US-data, the disasters happend in the US are of primary interest. But, given that economies are linked via international trade and globalization, I do want to use all the data.

**Preprocessing:**

To optain usable time-series, I thought of simply counting e.g. "disaster type" x "region" over time, like:

[image]

or the sum of all types per region:

[image]

Now, the first option would lead to a large number of features, containing mostly zeros. But on the other hand it would be nice to see if specific types have a certain influence.

Continuing with the second option and taking log-differences, I would encounter the obvious problems
[image]

Then I thought of a e.g. 12-month moving average and then taking log-differences:
[image]
[image]

But, doing so, I would feed the RNN a 12-month moving average of the total level of disasters and lose information on the influence of specific types.

**Questions:**

1. Going with the total of all types, is MA-log-difference a good idea for such kind of data or would you suggest otherwise? Maybe one of the other transformations mentioned in the paper? If so, why?
2. Is there a smart way to go with the specific disaster types?